# cup product on wedge of sphere of even and odd degree

Tags: ring-theory, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

For my class, I have to compute the cup product of $S^2\vee S^3\vee S^4 \vee ...\vee S^n \vee S^{n+1}=X$ with $\mathbb{Z}$ coefficients and $\mathbb{F}_2$ coefficients .

If I take $x_p\in H^p(X)\cong H^p(S^p)$ and $x_q \in H^q(X)\cong H^q(S^q)$ two generator and we write $u_k$ to be the generator of $H^k(S^k)$, then we have how can I deduce  $x_p \cup x_q $ from $u_p \cup u_q$ if there was only 2 wedge I could use the fact that the inclusion $$S^p\vee S^p\to S^p\vee S^p\vee S^l $$
is a retract, but I'm not sure if I can use it here since we have more wedge summand.

Comment: What are the dot dot dots? $S^2\vee S^3\vee S^4\vee\cdots?$

Comment: I've edited the post!

Comment: The cohomology ring of $H^*(S^2\vee\ldots\vee S^{n+1})$ is isomorphic to a subring of $H^*(S^2)\oplus\ldots\oplus H^*(S^{n+1})$, which contains everything in positive degree (some subtlety for degree 0). This is given by MV sequence, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2593381/724407) for example. The cup product structure for the wedge sum can then be deduced from the cohomology ring of spheres.

Comment: @FShrike Are you sure you're computing $\text{Ext}(\Bbb Z,\Bbb F_2)$ correctly?

Comment: @Kevin.S points out https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2593340/42781. I think this question is a duplicate (indeed a special case) of that.

Comment: @TedShifrin Ah whoops. That’s obviously zero. I was computing $\mathsf{Ext}(\Bbb F_2,\Bbb F_2)$… which is fine (up to a slightly different but isomorphic definition of cohomology with coefficients) except that I should beware in which category the extension is computed. $\mathsf{Ext}_{\Bbb Z}^1(\Bbb F_2,\Bbb F_2)\cong\Bbb F_2$ but $\mathsf{Ext}^1_{\Bbb F_2}(\Bbb F_2,\Bbb F_2)=0$ and the latter is the one that is actually relevant